# nginx + nestjs (API) + angular (CLIENT) Deployment CORS error

Tags: angular, nginx, cors, nestjs

I'am trying to deploy a project with nestjs and angular. My project folder like this,

**/var/www/miservicio.gal (Nestjs app)**

**/var/www/miservicio.gal/public (Angular app)**

I define Server in nginx:

```
server {

    server_name miservicio.gal;
    root /var/www/miservicio.gal;
    index index.html;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Ugrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


    }
```

In Nestjs:

```js
app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  rootPath: join(__dirname, 'public'),
  exclude: ['/api/(.*)'],
})
```

When I access the app on https://miservicio.gal I get the app's home screen. The error occurs when I call the API from the application. For example: https://miservicio/api/calendario/2024. Then it gives me back a cors error:

> Cross-origin request blocked: The same origin policy does not allow
> reading from remote resources in
> http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/calendario/2024. (Reason: Unsuccessful CORS
> request.) Status code: (null).

In nestjs app I define Cors:

```js
app.enableCors({
                origin: [
                'http://127.0.0.1',
                'http://127.0.0.1:5555',
                'http://localhost:5555',
                'http://miservicio.gal',
                'https://miservicio.gal',
                ],
                methods: ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
                credentials: true,
        });
```

The request header are:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/calendario/2024

Transferido0 GB (tamaño 0 GB)

Política de referenciastrict-origin-when-cross-origin

Resolución DNSSistema

Accept application/json, text/plain, */*

authorization "Bearer eyJhbGciO.......

Connection keep-alive

Host 127.0.0.1:5555

Origin https://miservicio.gal

Sec-Fetch-Dest empty

Sec-Fetch-Mode cors

Sec-Fetch-Site cross-site

Sec-GPC 1

User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0
```

I've tried everything and I can't get it to work.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.